# Is there a design pattern to force initialization of a subclass implemented method?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm trying to create an abstract class in Java where part of its creation involves calling an initialization method that the subclass needs to implement. I want the subclass to have access to arbitrary parameters, however, that the abstract class doesn't need to know about.

Here's some code to make it more clear:

```
public abstract class NormalizedRandom<T> {

    private Queue<T> randomList;
    private List<T> usedRandomsList;

    public NormalizedRandom() {
        randomList = new LinkedList<T>();
        usedRandomsList = new ArrayList<T>();
        init();
        shuffleList();
    }

    protected abstract void init();

    ...

}
```

And

```
public class NormalizedRandomIntegerRange extends NormalizedRandom<Integer> {

    private int min;
    private int max;
    private int repeats;

    public NormalizedRandomIntegerRange(int min, int max, int repeats) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.repeats = repeats;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        for(int num = min; num <= max; num++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < repeats; i++) {
                super.addRandomOutcome(num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this isn't going to work because super() needs to get called before I can initialize the parameters.

This sort of problem looks like there has to be some easy design pattern to solve it. I just can't think of the right way to solve it offhand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to roll out the initialization into an own class or interface, that 
the subclass has to provide the superclass as an argument for the constructor.
Now you can easily switch and redifine the init method and the 
super class can call it itself, before the subclass code will run.
The initStrategy can be initialized with arguments, that are not known from
the superclass. I would use an interface.
(I think you already know it, but it is a type of strategy pattern).

Hope this helps, Steve.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution I was going for. After giving it a bit more thought, I actually realized that I was over-architecting this problem. The hierarchy doesn't actually need to be that flexible: I'm actually just going to have the initialization happen in the subclass constructor and just need to remember to do it if I make more subclasses later on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a ´Builder´ which is the creational pattern used to avoid having many different constructors.
I mean getting the initialitation of the Objects out of the contructor.Using a Builder Class for that purpose.

Comment: Builder doesn't work as well as I would like because it adds an extra layer of indirection to the problem. I want the subclass to be able to define its initialization directly, which the Strategy pattern, which JacksOnF1re suggested, is able to do.